# Show that $x_{\alpha} \rightarrow x$ in $M$ iff $x_{\alpha}$ is eventually equal to x.

Tags: general-topology

Let $M$ be any metric space. A mapping $P(\alpha)=x_{\alpha}$ of $\Omega_0$ into $M$ will be a net; where $\Omega_0=\Omega - \{\omega_1\}$ and $\Omega$ denotes the set of ordinals $\leq \omega_1$. Show that $x_{\alpha} \rightarrow x$ in $M$ iff $x_{\alpha}$ is eventually equal to $x$.

My attempt

I proved the sufficiency by contradiction.

$x_{\alpha}$ is eventually equal to $x$, then exists $\alpha_0 \in \Omega_0$ such that if $\alpha \geq \alpha_0$, $x_{\alpha}=x$. Let $U$ a open neighborhood of $x$ ($x \in U$) such that $\forall \alpha' \in \Omega_0 $, $x_{\alpha'}$ doesn't belong in $U$. Take a $\alpha^* \geq \alpha_0$, then $x_{\alpha^*}$ doesn't belong in $U$ then $x$ doesn't belong in $U$.

Could you guide me with the first part and if what I did is correct?

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1894387/a-net-varphi-0-omega-1-to-m-on-a-metric-space-m-converges-iff-var?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

For each $n \in \mathbb N$, there exist $\alpha_n \in \omega_1$ such that, for all $\alpha\gt\alpha_1$, $d(x_\alpha, x_0)\lt\frac{1}{n}$. Let $\beta = \sup{\alpha_n}\lt\omega_1$. Then $d(x_\alpha, x_0) = 0$ for all $\alpha \ge\beta$.