# Net in a Metric Space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, ordinals, nets

I'm self-studying Willard's *General Topology*.  I'm stumped on exercise 11A(3), which reads:

> Let $M$ be any metric space.  A mapping $P(\alpha) = x_\alpha$ of $\Omega_0$ into $M$ will be a net.  Show that $x_\alpha \longrightarrow x$ in $M$ if and only if $x_\alpha$ is eventually equal to $x$.

For reference, $\omega_1$ is the first uncountable ordinal and $\Omega_0$ is the set of ordinals less than $\omega_1$.

I'm not looking for a solution; I'd like to solve this problem myself.  However, I'd appreciate any hints or tips you can provide.

Many thanks!

Doug

Comment: There is this older question: [A net $\varphi : [0, \omega_1) \to M$ on a metric space $M$ converges $\iff \varphi$ is eventually constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1894387). *But since you wrote that you want to try it yourself, you should resist peeking in there for  bit.)

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that.  Thanks!  You're right, I don't want take a look at that solution yet, but I'll eventually look at it to compare against my solution (or if I give up!).

Answer (score 3):

HINT: If the net converges to $x$, then for each $n<\omega$ there is an $\alpha_n<\omega_1$ such that $x_\alpha\in B(x,2^{-n})$ whenever $\alpha_n\le\alpha<\omega_1$. I’ve left an additional hint in the spoiler-protected box below.

> Now consider $\sup_{n<\omega}\alpha_n$ and $\bigcap_{n<\omega}B(x,2^{-n})$.

Comment: Thanks!  I haven't clicked on the spoiler box, but I like that approach.  Let me noodle on this after work and see if I can solve it.  Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: @Doug: You’re welcome!

Comment: I got the answer (thankfully without looking at your spoiler!).  While in the shower, I realized that the supremum of that countable subset of Omega_0 is key.  Much thanks!

Comment: @Doug: You’re very welcome!